# Azure Function with Event Grid run local without ngrok

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an app that uses AzureFunction and EventGrid with Nodejs. I want to debug some Event Trigger Functions in localhost, but I don't want to use Ngrok, for particular reasons. There is another way to achieve EventGrid debugging without Ngrok?

Comment: at the end eventgridtrigger are just http trigger so you should be able to send data from postman to your local function app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running Azure function locally, the EventGridTrigger can be access through this url:

```
http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName={functionname}
```

From Postman (for example), you would need these additional headers:

- **Content-Type**: `application/json`
- **aeg-event-type**: `Notification`

A full http request would looks like this

```http
POST /runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName={functionname}
Host: http://localhost:7071
Content-Type: application/json
aeg-event-type: Notification

{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/5b4b650e-28b9-4790-b3ab-ddbd88d727c4/resourcegroups/test/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/test",
  "subject": "eventhubs/test",
  "eventType": "captureFileCreated",
  "eventTime": "2017-07-14T23:10:27.7689666Z",
  "id": "7b11c4ce-1c34-4416-848b-1730e766f126",
  "data": {
    "fileUrl": "https://test.blob.core.windows.net/debugging/testblob.txt",
    "fileType": "AzureBlockBlob",
    "partitionId": "1",
    "sizeInBytes": 0,
    "eventCount": 0,
    "firstSequenceNumber": -1,
    "lastSequenceNumber": -1,
    "firstEnqueueTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "lastEnqueueTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}
```

[image: Calling Azure Function EventgridTrigger from Postman]

[image: VS Code debug - Azure Function EventgridTrigger]

Comment: Thank you for your response Thomas, I get it now.